# After killing a pid in shell script, it remains there in the same script?

Tags: shell, kill-process

I'm trying to kill a process, then verify if it's killed successfully. However I found that although it's killed, in the same script it still shows it's not killed. My script is like the following (running in a remote server by ssh first, that's why you see the remote parameter \$pid):

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep 'someprog' | grep sh | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2` 
if [ ! -z "\$pid" ]; then
    echo kill pid: \$pid
    kill -9 \$pid
    sleep 10
fi

pid1=`ps -ef | grep 'someprog' | grep sh | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2`
if [ ! -z "\$pid1" ]; then
    echo \$pid1 is not killed yet
fi
```

Although I have "sleep 10", and I checked in another terminal this pid is gone, The test of pid1 is still true, and print the line "$pid1 is not killed yet". Can anyone help me so that I won't get into printing that line when it's already killed?

Comment: All your `\`\`` command expansions happen on the client side

Comment: Yes I'm ssh-ing to another machine and issue the scripts here. Any problem with this practice?

Comment: Yes. You have to make sure expansions happen on the machine you want.

Comment: I have another terminal ssh to the same remote server, and I can verify there, that the scripts are executed, and the pid is killed successfully.

Comment: The code I posted above are within ssh Here document.

Comment: All your `\`\`` expansions happen on the client side. You have to make sure they happen on the machine you want. Most likely you will want to add ``\ `` in front of each backtick. This is the same reasoning that made you put it in front of your `$`

Comment: Do you mean in my script replace all \$pid with \\$pid ? But it reports syntax error for me. Actually I think it got expanded in the remote server, as I printed out the pid and it is the same as the pid I'm looking for in the remote server. If the expansion is in my client side, there's no such pid and shouldn't print anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're seeing the markup properly or if you are misreading the description. Backticks are the apostrophes that tilt backwards. For example, you write this: ``pid=`ps -ef ....``. Right after the equals sign, there is a backtick character. You must escape the backtick characters.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood you earlier. Now it works. Thank you so much, saved my day!

Comment: Since you don't appear to be mixing local and remote execution in this example (it's hard to tell since you didn't include the vital ssh or heredoc parts), you can just remove the escaping and instead quote the heredoc word, e.g. `<< 'EOF'` instead of `<< EOF`